# Adding OrderBy to an EF query causes OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

**EDIT** - This only happens when I add `OrderBy` before the projection.  If I add it after the projection, the query is very quick and has no out of memory problem!  I used Linq Pad to check the gen'ed SQL.  When I do the order by before the projection the SQL is hundreds of lines longer and has far more projections in it than when it after.

Here's a significantly shortened example of sorting pre projection

```
from contact in Contacts
orderby contact.ContactID
let DefaultAddress = contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsDefault.HasValue && x.IsDefault.Value)
select new {
    ContactID = contact.ContactID,
    DefaultAddressLine2 = DefaultAddress.Line2
}
```

And the same example, but sorted post projection

```
from contact in Contacts
let DefaultAddress = contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsDefault.HasValue && x.IsDefault.Value)
select new {
    ContactID = contact.ContactID,
    DefaultAddressLine2 = DefaultAddress.Line2
} into x
orderby x.ContactID
select x
```

The second example results in a straight SELECT FROM with a single OUTER APPLY for the address.  The first results in two OUTER APPLY's.  In the full version of the query, this same "doubling" of the outer apply happens exponentially and I end up with hundreds of extra applys!

**ORIGINAL** - I have a query to return contacts along with their default address, phone number, and e-mail along these lines

```
from contact in Db.Contacts
select new
{
Contact = contact,
DefaultAddress = contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsDefault.HasValue && x.IsDefault.Value),
DefaultPhone = contact.Phones.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsDefault.HasValue && x.IsDefault.Value),
DefaultEmail = contact.Emails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsDefault.HasValue && x.IsDefault.Value)
} into withDefaults
select new ContactWithDefaultsModel
{
ContactID = withDefaults.Contact.ContactID,

Surname = withDefaults.Contact.ESurname,
First = withDefaults.Contact.EFirst,

// other contact props

DefaultAddressLine2 = withDefaults.DefaultAddress != null ? withDefaults.DefaultAddress.Line2 : null,
DefaultAddressCityID = withDefaults.DefaultAddress != null ? withDefaults.DefaultAddress.CityID : null,
DefaultAddressStateID = withDefaults.DefaultAddress != null ? withDefaults.DefaultAddress.StateID : null,
DefaultAddressCountryID = withDefaults.DefaultAddress != null ? withDefaults.DefaultAddress.CountryID : null,
DefaultAddressZip = withDefaults.DefaultAddress != null ? withDefaults.DefaultAddress.Zip : null,

// same for default phone/email
}
```

That query works fine, but when I add an OrderBy, even for something simple like `OrderBy(x => x.ContactID)`, the query crashes with an `OutOfMemoryException`.

I can see from the stack trace that it has something to do with the query plan compiler, but I can't see what the cause is.  Here's the full stack trace.

```
at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmType.get_Identity()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.TypeUsage.BuildIdentity(StringBuilder builder)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.RowType.GetRowTypeIdentityFromProperties(IEnumerable`1 properties, InitializerMetadata initializerMetadata)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.RowType..ctor(IEnumerable`1 properties, InitializerMetadata initializerMetadata)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.TypeUsage.get_ModelTypeUsage()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.Internal.ArgumentValidation.ValidateProperty(DbExpression instance, String propertyName, Boolean ignoreCase, EdmMember& foundMember)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.DbExpressionBuilder.PropertyByName(DbExpression instance, String propertyName, Boolean ignoreCase)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.BindingScope.TryResolveVar(Var targetVar, DbExpression& resultExpr)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.ResolveVar(Var referencedVar)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(VarRefOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.VarRefOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(ComparisonOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ComparisonOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(ConditionalOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ConditionalOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(FilterOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.FilterOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitAsRelOp(Node inputNode)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.BuildProjection(Node relOpNode, IEnumerable`1 projectionVars)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(SingleRowOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.SingleRowOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitAsRelOp(Node inputNode)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitApply(Node applyNode, DbExpressionKind applyKind)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(OuterApplyOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.OuterApplyOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitAsRelOp(Node inputNode)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitApply(Node applyNode, DbExpressionKind applyKind)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(OuterApplyOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.OuterApplyOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitAsRelOp(Node inputNode)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitApply(Node applyNode, DbExpressionKind applyKind)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(OuterApplyOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.OuterApplyOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitAsRelOp(Node inputNode)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitApply(Node applyNode, DbExpressionKind applyKind)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(OuterApplyOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.OuterApplyOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitAsRelOp(Node input…tOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator..ctor(Command itree, Node toConvert)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.ProviderCommandInfoUtils.Create(Command command, Node node)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CodeGen.Process(List`1& childCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(DbCommandTree ctree, List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.CreateCommandDefinition(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<BufferResponseContentAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure that this will help, but you're giving the plan compiler an awful lot to do that's not necessary. Removing all redundancies, your query could look like this:

```
from contact in Db.contacts
let DefaultAddress = contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsDefault.Value)
let DefaultPhone = contact.Phones.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsDefault.Value)
let DefaultEmail = contact.Emails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsDefault.Value)
select new contactWithDefaultsModel
{
    contactID = contact.contactID,
    Surname = contact.ESurname,
    First = contact.EFirst,

    // other contact props

    DefaultAddressLine2 = DefaultAddress.Line2,
    DefaultAddressCityID = DefaultAddress.CityID,
    DefaultAddressStateID = DefaultAddress.StateID,
    DefaultAddressCountryID = DefaultAddress.CountryID,
    DefaultAddressZip = DefaultAddress.Zip,

    // same for default phone/email
}
```

Here's what I changed:

- Removed the projection to an intermediate anonymous type and replaces this by `let` calls.
- Removed all `null` checks. This can be done safely, because the entire expression is translated into SQL, which doesn't have a null reference concept. In fact, SQL has null propagation that C# now also has, but without the explicit operator (`?`). Leaving these null checks here will get them translated into the final SQL query, where they're redundant.

This should give the plan compiler less code to chew on and hopefully skirt around this exception.

Comment: It's still a *very* slow query on the first run when it's compiling, but those two changes were enough to avoid the `OutOfMemoryException`!  In the future, are there any good strategies to help identify which areas of a query are causing trouble so I can rewrite them?

Comment: Try to avoid too many joins in one query. It may be more efficient to fetch the default data in three separate queries. That's both easier for the expression translator and the query optimizer in the SQL database.

Comment: Do you mean fetch it in 3 queries and join it w/ the contact record in memory, or do you mean write queries for the default addr, phone, and email and join those to the contact?

Comment: I mean the first option. In effect, you'll have 4 SQL queries sent to the database.

Comment: How would I sort or filter by data in the defaults table if I load it as a separate query?  (Not sure if this is a separate question).

Comment: You could opt for ordering in memory after you constructed the `ContactWithDefaultsModel`s. Otherwise the only option is to work with the single query. Making stuff perform well hardly ever makes code look better :(

Comment: Please see edited question - I've narrowed the cause down to what seems to be a problem w/ SQL generation when order by is applied pre projection.

Comment: Maybe you should show in code what you mean by "before" and "after" the projection, also to make clear what exactly you are sorting.

Comment: Edited.  I'm just sorting on the PK for testing.  In practice I would want to sort on any prop of the contact.

Comment: I think this turns it into a different question. For now, we managed to get away from OOM. The running query shows new peculiarities that we should try to tackle in a new post.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because you has insufficient memory to allocate for large results.You could sort the list in place, using List.Sort, which uses the Quicksort algorithm. But of course, your original list would be sorted

> Contacts.Sort(x => x.CompareTo(ContactID));